# Open downloaded files in webview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I am new to iphone development. I am developing an iphone application in which i am downloading files using web service with following code:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileLoc = [basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/filename.pdf"];
NSData *fileData = [self decodeBase64WithString:soapResults];
[fileData writeToFile:fileLoc atomically:YES];
```

And my file is in path : /Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0/Applications/7A627E64-DEAB-40FA-BE04-35ED50580B65/filename.pdf

How can i open this file using uiwebview??? I tried this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileLoc = [basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/filename"];
[self loadDocument:fileLoc inView:mywebview];
```

My loadDocument method is:

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];  
}
```

But it showing error... I think location is the problem.. How can i find the path in simulator as well as in orignal device???

Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathForResource:ofType:` can only be used to load resource files, which are shipped as part of your application bundle.  You're trying to load a downloaded file from your Documents directory.  So you should be able to just do

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileLoc = [basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/filename.pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLoc];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Yes.  `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns appropriate paths for both device and simulator.

Comment: @cduhn  i'm dowloading my pdf file with the timestamp, something like this: /Documents/myPDF.pdf1382698338.78128 so now how can i appendpathComponent ??

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? What does your `loadDocument` method look like? You should load the document into the WebView something like this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLoc]]];
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add loadDocument method.. Now i added it.. Please check.. It is same as you said... And my error is : "[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter" in console...